# Running Fabric CA natively - Could not find default `PKCS11` BCCSP

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, pkcs#11, hyperledger-fabric-ca, softhsm

Attempting to configure HSM according to:
https://hyperledger-fabric-ca.readthedocs.io/en/release-1.4/users-guide.html#configuring-an-hsm

**but** trying to do so running the Fabric CA Server as a **systemd service** according to: 
https://upcloud.com/community/tutorials/hyperledger-fabric-systemd/

I followed a combo of the above link and this link:
https://gist.github.com/AkshayCHD/f7c96175dca1e5ab8d5785a3af0d5692

**BUT** I built it with "GO_TAGS=pkcs11 make fabric-ca-server" according to this:
https://jira.hyperledger.org/browse/FAB-13458

I installed SoftHSM according to the below link and can initialize the token:
https://wiki.opendnssec.org/display/SoftHSMDOCS/SoftHSM+Documentation+v2#SoftHSMDocumentationv2-Download

I initialize the server before starting so I can edit the fabric-ca-server-config.yaml with the appropriate PKCS11 data.

I can start the server/service fine without PKCS11 but when I edit the fabric-ca-server-config.yaml file to the below it never works.

INTERESTINGLY when I switch the default to "SW" I receive:
**Error: Failed to initialize BCCSP Factories: Failed initializing PKCS11.BCCSP %!s(): Could not initialize BCCSP PKCS11 [Failed initializing PKCS11 library /home/ubuntu/softhsm/SoftHSMv2/src/lib/.libs/libsofthsm2.so ForFabric: Could not get Slot List [pkcs11: 0x190: CKR_CRYPTOKI_NOT_INITIALIZED]]**

BUT when I have "default: PKCS11" I get this error:
**Could not find default `PKCS11` BCCSP**

I have read this https://jira.hyperledger.org/browse/FAB-9595 but AGAIN I'm not using Docker.

Any help or pointers in the right direction would be appreciated.

Relevant output:

bccsp: 
    default: PKCS11
    pkcs11:
        Library: /home/ubuntu/softhsm/SoftHSMv2/src/lib/.libs/libsofthsm2.so
        Pin: 98765432
        Label: ForFabric
        hash: SHA2
        security: 256
        filekeystore:
      # The directory used for the software file-based keystore
            keystore: msp/keystore
    sw:
        hash: SHA2
        security: 256
        filekeystore:
            # The directory used for the software file-based keystore
            keystore: msp/keystore

fabric-ca-server:

Version: 2.0.0-snapshot-d780eb0

Go version: go1.13.5

OS/Arch: linux/amd64

Comment: Can you start the fabric-ca-server with the `-d` option?  I believe your problem is that you have not initialized SoftHSM ... but it's odd that you don't get that error when setting default to PKCS11 and only to SW.  We might be eating that error internally hence the reason for `-d` to output debug statements.

Comment: [DEBUG] Initializing BCCSP: &{ProviderName:pkcs11 SwOpts:0xc000080940 Pkcs11Opts:0xc0004c89c0}
[DEBUG] Initializing BCCSP with software options &{SecLevel:256 HashFamily:SHA2 Ephemeral:false FileKeystore:0xc000045790 DummyKeystore:<nil> InmemKeystore:<nil>}
[DEBUG] Initializing BCCSP with PKCS11 options &{SecLevel:256 HashFamily:SHA2 Ephemeral:false Library:/usr/local/lib/softhsm/libsofthsm2.so Label:ForFabric Pin:98765432 SoftVerify:false Immutable:false}
[DEBUG] Closing server DBs
Error: Failed to initialize BCCSP Factories: %!s(<nil>)
Could not find default `pkcs11` BCCSP

Comment: I uploaded more text to chat due to character limitation. PKCS#11 command /fab-ca/server$ pkcs11-tool --module /home/ubuntu/softhsm/SoftHSMv2/src/lib/.libs/libsofthsm2.so -l -t
Using slot 0 with a present token (0xeb0f89e)
Logging in to "ForFabric".
Please enter User PIN: 
C_SeedRandom() and C_GenerateRandom():
  seems to be OK
Digests:
  all 4 digest functions seem to work
  MD5: OK
  SHA-1: OK
Signatures: not implemented
Verify (currently only for RSA):
  No private key found for testing
Unwrap: not implemented
Decryption (RSA)
No errors

Answer (score 1):

After executing `GO_TAGS=pkcs11 make fabric-ca-server`, remember to remove the original fabric-ca-server binary and put the newly built binary in `path/to/go/bin`

Answer (score 0):

The issue encountered was a combination of creating the tokens as one user and starting the service as another (sudo).  Creating the token and starting the Fabric CA server as root (sudo -i) solved this issue.

> root@ip-172-31-85-208:~/fab-ca/server# fabric-ca-server start -b
>   admin:adminpw 2020/01/10 17:57:31 [INFO] Configuration file location:
>   /root/fab-ca/server/fabric-ca-server-config.yaml 2020/01/10 17:57:31
>   [INFO] Starting server in home directory: /root/fab-ca/server
>   2020/01/10 17:57:31 [INFO] Server Version: 2.0.0-snapshot-d780eb0
>   2020/01/10 17:57:31 [INFO] Server Levels: &{Identity:2 Affiliation:1
>   Certificate:1 Credential:1 RAInfo:1 Nonce:1} 2020/01/10 17:57:31
>   [INFO] The CA key and certificate already exist 2020/01/10 17:57:31
>   [INFO] The key is stored by BCCSP provider 'PKCS11' 2020/01/10
>   17:57:31 [INFO] The certificate is at: /root/fab-ca/server/ca-cert.pem
>   2020/01/10 17:57:31 [INFO] Initialized sqlite3 database at
>   /root/fab-ca/server/fabric-ca-server.db 2020/01/10 17:57:31 [INFO] The
>   Idemix issuer public and secret key files already exist 2020/01/10
>   17:57:31 [INFO]    secret key file location:
>   /root/fab-ca/server/msp/keystore/IssuerSecretKey 2020/01/10 17:57:31
>   [INFO]    public key file location:
>   /root/fab-ca/server/IssuerPublicKey 2020/01/10 17:57:31 [INFO] The
>   Idemix issuer revocation public and secret key files already exist
>   2020/01/10 17:57:31 [INFO]    private key file location:
>   /root/fab-ca/server/msp/keystore/IssuerRevocationPrivateKey 2020/01/10
>   17:57:31 [INFO]    public key file location:
>   /root/fab-ca/server/IssuerRevocationPublicKey 2020/01/10 17:57:31
>   [INFO] Home directory for default CA: /root/fab-ca/server 2020/01/10
>   17:57:31 [INFO] Operation Server Listening on 127.0.0.1:9443
>   2020/01/10 17:57:31 [INFO] Listening on http://0.0.0.0:7054